# Spring AOP on annotation doesn't trigger

Tags: spring, annotations, spring-aop

For a project, I'm trying to implement my own @Secured(security level) annotation, which should check the security level of the user and have the method validated depending on whether the user has "clearance" or not. I tried building it, but for some reason, my aspect's code doesn't seem to trigger. No errors are given in the log either. I wasn't able to find a proper solution to the problem here on Stackoverflow.

I could use spring security, but due to the nature of the project, customizing it would be far more effort than just being able to use my own custom annotation. I'm using this in a spring-mvc configuration.

The relevant code is:

```
public enum SecurityRole {
    ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Secured {
    SecurityRole value();
}




@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @Secured
    public String listContacts(Map<String, Object> map, HttpSession session) {
        if (session.isNew())
            session.setAttribute("test", 123);
        session.setAttribute("test", (Integer) session.getAttribute("test") + 1);
        System.out.println(session.getAttribute("test"));
        map.put("user", new User());
        map.put("userList", userService.listUser());
        return "user";
    }
}



@Aspect
public class SecurityAspect {

    @Pointcut(value = "execution(public * *(..))")
    public void anyPublicMethod() {
    }

    @Around("anyPublicMethod() && @annotation(securityRole)")
    public Object secure(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Secured securityRole)
            throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("called secured!");
        System.out.println(securityRole.value());
        return pjp.proceed();
    }
}
```

(root-context.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop  
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">
    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <bean id="securityMonitor" class="com.blafoo.usersystem.aspects.SecurityAspect" />
</beans>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
```

only applies to the beans defined in the same context. In your `root-context.xml`, you only have one bean defined, `securityMonitor`. Therefore your `@Controller` bean (probably declared in server context) is not advised.